# Error in getting the InstanceID BizTalk

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, biztalk, biztalk-2010

Is there a known issue in this code for BizTalk 2010?

```
string InstanceID = Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.RootService.InstanceId.ToString()
```

We keep encountering the error "Object Reference not set to an instance object" whenever we used that line.  What's weird is that even if we put an if condition to check if that line is null before converting it to string, we still hit the error.

Comment: The "Object Reference" is not the problem, don't close for that.

Comment: In what are you trying to use that code?   A Orchestration (what shape), a pipeline component, a map?

Answer (score 1):

So, the BizTalk Answer to this question is, *you should not be doing this*.

If you explain a bit about exactly what you're trying to do, I will amend the Answer with a better solution.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why not to use this? I haven't had any issue with this specific code (retrieving instance id from an orchestration).

Comment: Because digging around in the internal, undocumented, object model is questionable at best.  If we get some insight from the OP, I am very, very confident there is a more appropriate means to satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do that in an Orchestration you should be defining the InstanceID as a variable in the Orchestration view, rather then trying to define it in your code as a String.

e.g.

[image]

And your code should be

```
InstanceID = Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.RootService.InstanceId.ToString();
```